# conditional multi line string in python

Tags: python, string, if-statement

what I try to do is basically:

```
cond = True

string_ = (cond*'a '
          'b '
          (not cond)*'c ')
```

if the variable `cond = True` the string_ should be 'a b ' but if I assign `cond = False` the string_ variable should be 'b c '.

Sure there is different solutions but I want to do this in a single line way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code would work as written if you wrap it in `''.join([ ])` add some commas.

Comment: Alternatively, use `if` statements and the `+` operator.

Comment: Most simply just use `(cond*'a ' + 'b ' + (not cond)*'c ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your [string multiplication](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) approach work if you wrap it with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
cond = True

string_ = "".join(
    [
        cond * "a ",
        "b ",
        (not cond) * "c ",
    ]
)

print(f"{string_=}")
```

which outputs

```
string_='a b '
```

This is arguably not the most readable approach, but it does extend nicely to arbitrarily many conditional components. You can of course make it a bit more readable if you swap the string multiplcation with some [ternary expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
cond = True

string_ = "".join(
    [
        "a " if cond else "",
        "b ",
        "c " if not cond else "",
    ]
)

print(f"{string_=}")
```

which outputs

```
string_='a b '
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
string_ = f"{a if cond else ''} {b} {'' if cond else c} "
```

if you meant a and c to be variables, or

```
string_ = f"{'a' if cond else ''} {b} {'' if cond else 'c'} "
```

if not.

You could also do:

```
string_ = f"{a} {b} " if cond else f"{b} {c} "
```

or

```
string_ = "a b " if cond else "b c "
```

which I'd find easier to read.

You can do:

```
string_ = f"{cond * 'a '}b {(not cond) * 'c '}'
```

but I doubt your coworkers would thank you - its a mental leap to associate multiplication with conditionals. Write your intentions - Python provides great tools to allow you to do that.

The `f` in `f"..."` is for "format string interpolation". You can place any python expression in the curly braces and python will call `str(<expression>)` on it and add it to the string. (See great comment below from Brian).

This also lets python optimize the construction of the string.

Comment: To be pedantic, expressions in an f-string are evaluated like `format(<expression>)`, not `str(<expression>)`, though the two are often the same. But you can easily construct a case where they differ just by defining `__format__` on a class

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to be so clever. Instead, just use `if` statements and `+`:

```
string_ = ''

if cond:
  string += 'a'

string += 'b'

if not cond
  string += 'c'
```

This will be much easier to read when you have to come back and make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you using this code will give you the desired output:

```py
cond = True
string_ = ''.join(['a '*(cond), 'b ', 'c '*(not cond)])
print(string_) 
#output ==> a b
```

For `cond = False` prints:

```py
b c
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
cond = True

string_ = f'{cond * "a "}b{(not cond) * " c"}'
print(string_)
```

Prints:

```
a b
```

---

For `cond = False` prints:

```
b c
```